# Is there any way to map jsonProperty of nested fields within an object?

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-boot, design-patterns

I have two classes Car.java and Bus.java

```
        Car.java   
        private Property property;
```

```
       Bus.java
       private Property property;
```

The Property.java class has number and colour.

```
        Property.java
        private String number;
        private String colour;
```

Depending on where it is called from, Car.java or Bus.java ,I want the properties field to be called carNumber, carColour, busNumber, busColour respectively in the output json.

Is there any way to achieve this using a single property class?
The output json should be 
"Car":{
     "Property" : {
           "carNumber" : "num"
           "carColor" : "blue"
     }
}

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can use `@JsonUnwrapped` with `prefix`.

```
// Car.Java 

@JsonUnwrapped(prefix="car-")
private Property property;
```

It will generate JSON as below (after serialization)

```
{ "car-name": "car name", "car-number" : "car number" }
```

Comment: But wouldnt this generate car-number and car-name directly under parent object? I still want it to be inside property.
Car { 
      Property { "carNumber" : "carNum" , "carColor" : "blue" }}

Comment: Correct, it would generate outside. to achieve within the `property` object, you have to go with custom serializer and deserializer. @ambiguos. there is this really good article you can follow https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-custom-serialization